# Adding subview to static UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, static, addsubview

I have a `static UITableView`. I'm trying to programmatically add a `UISegmentedControl` to the third cell. Here is the code:

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"First", @"Second"]];
segment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:segment];
```

When the code is called, the `SegmentedControl` isn't added.

I then tried adding a `UILabel`, and that doesn't work either.

I can't place it in that method because I'm adding the SegmentedControl when a button is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have static `tableView`, you can connect outlets to its cells directly and manipulate like simple subviews. So just connect outlet and use your code to add subviews. It will work

**UPDATE**

Add subviews using the following code:

```
[cell addSubview:segment];
```

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? I can't do it programmatically?

Comment: It is the simple one. You may even add SegmentedControl in storyboard/xib

Comment: I updated my answer, adding subviews to `contentView` is incorrect

Comment: So I mean you may use your code but add subviews not to `contentView` but directly to `cell`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77557/discussion-between-azat-and-jessica).

Answer (score 0):

Move your code into

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

then just reference the `cell` being passed by the method

Comment: I can't place it in that method because I'm adding the `SegmentedControl` when a `button` is selected.

Comment: Oh, ok, you should probably add that to your question as additional information.